# Giving controls to a game from a java code

Tags: java

I just want to know that how can I give controls (key values up, down, left, right arrow keys etc) to an installed desktop application game from my own Java program? The game is already installed on the system and now I want to give key values directly from my code.

Comment: Your question is far to vague.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the api:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: what functions should i use to connect my code to the game and tell me the stepeise procedure

Answer (score 0):

A lot of games store key configs in unprotected text files. You could just figure out the name and write a regex to change it however you like. Other than that, it may be fairly difficult if the game doesn't have an official API or some such.

Answer (score 0):

AWT Robot class seems to be able to generate mouse and keyboard events. But I am not sure if it can dedicate that only to one program.